# truffle migrate restarts from first migration after restarting testrpc

Tags: truffle, testrpc, truffle-migration, migration

I’m trying to create sort of private chain on testrpc so i use `testrpc -u 0 -d --db /path/to/db` to start testrpc each time. The thing is that if I restart testrpc (kill it and start it again) `truffle migrate` restarts migration process from the beginning (1_*) although testrpc uses old chain database. Is there a way around this or is this an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deploy a contract to your private chain. Truffle stores the network id of your chain to know on what chain it was deployed. ( with the address on the current chain )

in build/contract/yourContract.json there is a field

```
"networks": {
 "1": {  //live network
  "events": {},
  "links": {},
  "address": "0xd77d2a7a728dc7c7c58ac1bcfdfb35934b3ed066"
 },
 "15": { // network id I manually set
  "events": {},
  "links": {},
  "address": "0x1c10cbe2e883567eea5de1017f3d21b5b2600abb"
 },
 "1507630284099": { // timestamp generated by testrpc
  "events": {},
  "links": {},
  "address": "0xcdc26c0a2e7f43f4ad571373fc68c1a58ed8a25a"
 }
},
```

The issue you have is that you do not set your network id with testrpc.

use

> `-i` or `--network-id`: Specify the network id the TestRPC will use to
>   identify itself (defaults to the current time or the network id of the
>   forked blockchain if configured)  [doc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc#command-line)

`testrpc -u 0 -d --db /path/to/db --network-id=15`

to set an id so when you restart your testrpc you'll keep your database and when you'll run again `truffle migrate` it will tell you `Network up to date.`